# Appending to a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary, append

I want to append different values to the same dictionary structure inside a JSON list. Here is an example:

```
myJson = {"list": []}

element = {"value": []}
myJson["list"].append(element)
myJson["list"].append(element.copy())

myJson["list"][0]["value"].append("first")
myJson["list"][1]["value"].append("second")
print(myJson)
```

What this prints out is:

```
{'list': [{'value': ['first', 'second']}, {'value': ['first', 'second']}]}
```

But I want:

```
{'list': [{'value': ['first']}, {'value': ['second']}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? I created a copy of `element` so why is it still the same? Thanks!

Comment: You need to make a deep copy, `.copy` is only a shallow copy. `import copy` and use `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: You can also consider a list/dict comprehension `values = ['first', 'second']` and
`{'list': [{'value': [v]} for v in values]}`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. The other answers I found only said to do `element.copy()` so I was confused.